# Mutex when returning object value

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

If I understand how C++ compilers handle local variables then `IsShutdownInProgress()` does not need any locking since the `shutdownInProgress` static variable will be placed on the stack. Am I correct?

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        // Irrelevant code commented away
        static pthread_mutex_t mutex;
        static bool shutdownInProgress;
    public:
        static void ShutdownIsInProgress()
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
            shutdownInProgress = true;                  
            pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
        }

        static bool IsShutdownInProgress()
        {
            // pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
            // pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
            return shutdownInProgress;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Am I correct?

No. This will make a copy of it to return; but reading it to make that copy without synchronisation will give a *data race*, with undefined behaviour. You'll need to make a local copy of it with the mutex locked:

```
static bool IsShutdownInProgress()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    bool result = shutdownInProgress;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    return result;
}
```

or, using a less error-prone RAII lock type:

```
static bool IsShutdownInProgress()
{
    lock_guard lock(mutex);
    return shutdownInProgress;
}
```

In C++11, you might consider `std::atomic<bool>` for more convenient, and perhaps more efficient, access to simple types from multiple threads.

Answer (score 3):

Race conditions are unrelated to whether a variable is located on the heap or on the stack. A race condition is when one thread is modifying a variable (a memory location) and another thread is reading or modifying the same variable. There is no guarantee that the modification of a `bool` is atomic so the posted code has a race condition, and therefore undefined behaviour.

A fix would be to store the value of the `bool` when the mutex is held and return the variable:

```
static bool IsShutdownInProgress()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    bool result = shutdownInProgress;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return result;
}
```

c++11 introduced [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) that could be used and the use of the `lock_guard` would avoid the requirement of a temporary variable to store the `bool` value for return:

```
static std::mutex mtx_;
static bool IsShutdownInProgress()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx_);
    return shutdownInProgress;
}
```

c++11 also introduced [`std::atomic<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) that would ensure the modification is atomic and avoid the need for an explicit lock:

```
static std::atomic<bool> shutdownInProgress;
static bool IsShutdownInProgress()
{
    return shutdownInProgress;
}
```

If c++11 is unavailable to [`boost::atomic`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0_beta1/doc/html/atomic.html) was introduced in v1.53.0 and boost also has equivalent [`boost::mutex` and `boost::lock_guard`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it needs a lock

C++11's memory model states you have a *data race* if any threads are writing a value at the same time as another thread reading it. This is because both a read and/or a write may not be atomic.

In this case you will return a local from the function, but to get that local the compiler needs to copy the value in `shutdownInProgress`, which may be concurrently being changed by another thread calling `ShutdownIsInProgress()`.

An easy way to solve this is to make `shutdownInProgress` an atomic:

```
static std::atomic<bool> shutdownInProgress;
```

If you make it atomic, you don't need any locks at all for either function